# How to select multiple rows with same foreignKey, but one column has all values in a set

Tags: sql-server

So I'm currently working on a stored procedure that returns a table comprising of data about the user (user ID) and performance metrics (field, metric_obtained).  I was originally doing it so I would return all data back, but I was thinking it would be more efficient to return only people who meet the minimum to be recognized.  I've already filtered them out based on minimum requirement, but the thing is they can be qualified based on a combination of things, so if I have 3 metrics A, B, and C, one recognition can be for A and B, or another is just C.  I'm also not limited to a max of 3 or this wouldn't be a problem.

My tables look like this:

```
|Employee | Metric | Obtained|
|_________|________|_________|
| John    | Email  |  .98    |
| Sue     | Email  |  .99    |
| Sue     | Phone  |  .82    |
| Larry   | Email  |  .93    |
| Larry   | Phone  |  .83    |
| Jess    | Phone  |  .9     |
| Jess    | Email  |  .94    |
| Bob     | Phone  |  .99    |
```

So if I need to get back both Phone AND Email my results would look like this:

```
|Employee | Metric | Obtained|
|_________|________|_________|
| Sue     | Email  |  .99    |
| Sue     | Phone  |  .82    |
| Larry   | Email  |  .93    |
| Larry   | Phone  |  .83    |
| Jess    | Phone  |  .9     |
| Jess    | Email  |  .94    |
```

Like I said, this would be easy if I had a guaranteed number of metrics, but I don't.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Write 3 separate statements that give you what you want then use UNION  or UNION ALL to return 1 result set.  Then we can look at how we can do it without the unions, because as of now I have NO idea what you criteria is to return these results.

Comment: But again, I'm not guaranteed a set number of metrics.  One time it could be 3, one time it could be 2, one time it could be 12.

Comment: Personally I don't understand the question well enough to be able to help.

Comment: It's alright, it's pretty complicated, which is why I'm reaching out here for help.

Comment: Without knowing more about the rules of how you want to go from input to output it is going to be tricky to provide advice.